# Resource role in oracle

Tags: oracle10g

What is the difference between granting such roles as `CREATE TABLE, CREATE TRIGGER, CREATE PROCEDURE` to user directly and via the role resource. Is it good to grant these role via resource or directly to the user schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RESOURCE` role almost certainly contains more privileges than you actually want to grant a user and it probably doesn't include a number of privileges that you do want to grant.  So you would generally never grant users the `RESOURCE` role in a production system.  Instead, you'd create roles appropriate to your environment (i.e. a `DEVELOPER_ROLE`, an `ANALYST_ROLE`, etc.), grant appropriate privileges to those roles, and then grant those roles to the appropriate users.

The only time that it matters whether a privilege has been granted directly to a user or via a role is if the user is trying to exercise the privilege through a stored procedure.  If I've been granted the `CREATE TABLE` privilege through a role, I can create all the tables I want interactively.  But if I try to write a stored procedure that creates a table using dynamic SQL, I'll get an error.  Since you never want developers creating objects at runtime, however, this isn't generally a problem.  If you **really** wanted to allow this, however, you'd have to grant the owner of the procedure the `CREATE TABLE` privilege directly.